# Rails segmentation fault byebug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to test out my rails environment and create a test rail app, but I'm having problems with it. When I try to run rails server, this is what I get:

```
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/byebug-5.0.0/lib/byebug/byebug.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0033 p:-17551942720714 s:0115 e:000114 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0032 p:---- s:0113 e:000112 CFUNC  :require
c:0031 p:0007 s:0109 e:000108 TOP    /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/byebug-5.0.0/lib/byebug/core.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0030 p:---- s:0107 e:000106 CFUNC  :require
c:0029 p:0007 s:0103 e:000102 TOP    /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/byebug-5.0.0/lib/byebug.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0028 p:---- s:0101 e:000100 CFUNC  :require
c:0027 p:0037 s:0097 e:000096 BLOCK  /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0026 p:---- s:0094 e:000093 CFUNC  :each
c:0025 p:0053 s:0091 e:000090 BLOCK  /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
c:0024 p:---- s:0085 e:000084 CFUNC  :each
c:0023 p:0030 s:0082 e:000081 METHOD /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
c:0022 p:0017 s:0078 e:000077 METHOD /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134
c:0021 p:0049 s:0074 e:000073 TOP    /Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0072 e:000071 CFUNC  :require
c:0019 p:0014 s:0068 e:000067 BLOCK  /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78 [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0065 e:000064 CFUNC  :tap
c:0017 p:0031 s:0062 e:000061 METHOD /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75
c:0016 p:0033 s:0059 e:000058 METHOD /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39
c:0015 p:0116 s:0055 e:000054 TOP    /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17 [FINISH]
c:0014 p:---- s:0051 e:000050 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0056 s:0047 e:000046 TOP    /Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:8 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0045 e:000044 CFUNC  :load
c:0011 p:0125 s:0041 e:000040 METHOD /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28
c:0010 p:0011 s:0037 e:000036 METHOD /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7
c:0009 p:0015 s:0033 e:000032 METHOD /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26
c:0008 p:0292 s:0028 e:000027 TOP    /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0024 e:000023 CFUNC  :load
c:0006 p:0121 s:0020 e:000019 TOP    /Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0015 e:000014 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0114 s:0011 e:000010 TOP    /Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:13 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0020 s:0004 E:001340 EVAL   bin/rails:3 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:002000 TOP    [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
/Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
/Users/Andrea/railsbridge/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/byebug-5.0.0/lib/byebug.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/byebug-5.0.0/lib/byebug.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/byebug-5.0.0/lib/byebug/core.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/byebug-5.0.0/lib/byebug/core.rb:1:in `require'
```

Followed by another 900+ lines of detailing loaded features. At the end, terminal gives me a note saying

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and how should I fix it? I have tried uninstalling and installing sqlite3, then running `bundle update` and `bundle install`, but it does not work. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you start `rails console`, or do you get the same error?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error when typing `rails console`

Comment: Remove `gem 'byebug'` from your Gemfile, then run `bundle` and try `bundle exec rails c` again.

Comment: Okay how should I go about removing it? Would 'gem uninstall byebug' work?

Comment: You should be able to just remove the line mentioning byebug from your Gemfile, located in the main folder, which will tell Rails not to load it.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it didn't work.. just changed the error message to `/Users/Andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418`

Comment: So, the issue isn't related to byebug. That means it's probably an incompatibility with your installed Ruby and your system... which is super hard to debug. Try installing a different version of Ruby (e.g. `rvm install 2.1.5`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution to this? I just ran into this problem today.

Comment: I start getting this today using pry-byebug 3.3.0. I downgraded it to 3.2.0 and things started working again

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure if this is a general solution to the problem. However, I got

`/Users/Mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@insight-app/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]`

and reloaded the rvm environ by doing:

`rvm use ruby-2.2.5` (or whatever version is appropriate)

after the bundle install and I could then proceed with booting up rails. Hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on how general this is, and why it works